# How to get rid of \0 ending of a constant char

Tags: c++11

I have the following struct `RCD`

```
typedef struct RIFF_CHUNCK_DISCRIPTOR {
   char                RIFF[4];        // RIFF Header      Magic header
   int32_t             ChunkSize;      // RIFF Chunk Size  
   int32_t             WAVE[4];        // WAVE Header      

};
```

How could I define `"RIFF"` so that it returns `RIFF` instead of`RIFF\0`

[image: Which returns the letters]

Comment: "RIFF" does encode 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F', \0 and there is nothing you can do. If you want to compare, used memcmp (or simply four character comparisons). By the way, your code compares the addresses, not the contents.